# Question about functions in Sobolev space.

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces, normed-spaces

Let $\Omega$ be a bounded Lipschitz domain in $\mathbb{R}^n$. If I consider a function $g:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ which has the following properties:
$$
|g(x)|\leq M \qquad |g(x)-g(y)|\leq K|x-y|
$$
the function $u\in H^1(\Omega)$ and the composite function $g(u)$, can I say that:
$$
\|g(u)\|_{H^1(\Omega)}\leq\sqrt{|\Omega|(M^2+K^2)} \quad?
$$

Another question: is it possible to use this disequation?
$$
\|g(u)\|_{L^2(\partial\Omega)}\leq C_{tr}\|g(u)\|_{H^1(\Omega)}
$$

Comment: For smooth $g$ and $u$ you have $$\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} g(u(x)) = g'(u(x))\cdot \frac{\partial u}{\partial x_i}(x),$$ so the gradient of $u$ must appear on the right hand side.

Comment: So it is correct $\sqrt{|\Omega|(M^2+K^2\|\nabla u\|_{L^2}^2)}$?

Comment: When you have the $L^2$-norm of $\nabla u$ in it, that already contains the measure of $\Omega$. If $\lvert\Omega\rvert \geqslant 1$, you get just a weaker bound, but for $\lvert\Omega\rvert < 1$, it might be wrong to multiply. I think $\sqrt{\lvert\Omega\rvert M^2 + \lVert\nabla u\rVert_{L^2}^2 K^2}$ should be right.